# How do I open multiple connected .html files togehter as a website?

Tags: html

I have a local folder with 57 HTML files. The HTML files, when opened in a browser, contain a drop-down menu and the different choices here correspond to the other HTML files. So clicking an option in the drop-down menu should bring me to the page of another file.

How can I open all HTML files together so the connections between them work? I do not want the pages in separate tabs, but more like a website where I can click my way between the pages corresponding to the files using the drop-down menu.

I am on a Windows 10 laptop.

I have opened the files separately in chrome. When selecting an option in the drop-down menu, it brings me to the "File not found" error page.

Thankful for any input!

Comment: "When selecting an option in the drop-down menu, it brings me to the "File not found" error page" — That just implies that the URLs in the links are wrong.

Comment: In addition to @quentin answer: look at the links you set in your menu. Do they point to where the html files rely on your disk?

Comment: Yes I think you are right this is probably the issue. I have not worked with html files before and have not created them myself, they are output from another program, so was not sure how they work and connect to each other. I have found the menu paths so will try and update them. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have to change the destination (of each drop down) to the respective html files in your folder.